# Ruby - Creating Triangle Arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to create a triangular array in ruby. A triangular array is a multi-dimensional array, where the first array has 1 element, the second array has 2 elements, the third array has 3 elements, and so on. It would look something like this.

```
[[1],[3,7],[2,4,6],[9,8,13,11],[10,21,17,24,35],[47,26,31,55,72,49]
  => Each next array has 1 more element than the previous array.
```

In triangular format , it would look something like this

```
                        [1]
                       [3,7]
                      [2,4,6]
                    [9,8,13,11]
                 [10,21,17,24,35]
               [47,26,31,55,72,49]
```

As you can see, I would like all the values in my array to be random.

```
1st array => I would like it to have 1 random element
2nd array => I would like it to have 2 random elements
3rd array => I would like it to have 3 random elements
```

and so on.

Alright, I refactored the original code, to get this

```
def triangle_array(n)
  @array = [[]] * n
  index = 0
  while index < n
    @array[n] = (1..100).to_a.shuffle.first(n)
    index += 1
  end
  return @array
end
```

This fortunately made some progress, and it even returned the last array element. But it didn't return the first four.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`Enumerable#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-map):

```
(1..6).map { |i|
  (1..i).map { rand(100) }
}
# => [[24], [54, 57], [77, 86, 71], [94, 92, 0, 89],
#     [86, 16, 0, 44, 91], [95, 26, 43, 35, 53, 54]]
```

Comment: Nice.  I was in the middle of writing something similar but not nearly as elegant.

Comment: Simply amazing! Glad to know the solution was simple.

Answer (score 2):

I am thinking something like below :-

```
 Array.new(6) { |i| Array.new(i+1) { rand(100) } }
 # => => [[95], [7, 33], [77, 81, 32], [87, 1, 51, 70], 
 # [49, 18, 87, 55, 21], [99, 43, 8, 23, 53, 35]]
```

Check this awesome [`Array::new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-c-new) method.

Answer (score 0):

How does your code even run without throwing an exception?  I would think `array` would be undefined because you only defined `@array`.

I think the simplest way to fix it would be this:

```
def triangle_array
  array = [[], [], [], [], [], []]
  array[0] = [rand(100)]
  2.times {array[1] << rand(100)}
  3.times {array[2] << rand(100)}
  4.times {array[3] << rand(100)}
  5.times {array[4] << rand(100)}
  6.times {array[4] << rand(100)}
end
```

But a nice way to rewrite the method can be found in falsetru's answer.

Comment: I refactored my code just now. I meant to say [[]] * 6

Comment: `[[]] * 6` is a very interesting piece of code.  It only makes two arrays total.

Answer (score 0):

Something a little different:

```
require 'matrix'

n = 5
m = 100

Matrix.build(n) { |i,j| i<=j ? rand(m) : nil }
      .column_vectors
      .map { |e| e.to_a.compact }
  #=> [[25], [56, 77], [34, 7, 86], [81, 78, 67, 85], [81, 28, 56, 2, 8]]
```

We have:

```
x = Matrix.build(n) { |i,j| i<=j ? rand(m) : nil }
  #=> Matrix[[25, 56, 34, 81, 81], [nil, 77, 7, 78, 28],
  #          [nil, nil, 86, 67, 56], [nil, nil, nil, 85, 2],
  #          [nil, nil, nil, nil, 8]]

v = x.column_vectors
  #=> [Vector[25, nil, nil, nil, nil], Vector[56, 77, nil, nil, nil],
  #    Vector[34, 7, 86, nil, nil], Vector[81, 78, 67, 85, nil],
  #    Vector[81, 28, 56, 2, 8]]

v.map { |e| e.to_a.compact }
  #=> [[25], [56, 77], [34, 7, 86], [81, 78, 67, 85], [81, 28, 56, 2, 8]]
```